# Which Canadian provinces will do a direct swap with a Republic of Ireland driving licence?

Tags: canada, driving-license, ireland, driving

I have read online that some provinces in Canada allow a direct swap of a Republic of Ireland driving licence for a licence for that province (maybe Ontario and Saskatchewan). This is a fairly new arrangement. I can't find online a list of the provinces that allow this. What are all of the provinces that do a direct swap?

Comment: Note that when swapping, they count where the license was originally issued.  For example, Netherlands can swap with Québec but not Ontario, and of course Québec can swap with Ontario, but if I would swap my Netherlands license for a Québec one, I still could not swap the Québec one for an Ontario one, as it is still considered Netherlands-issued.

Answer (score 6):

I have found references for 3 Canadian provinces.

Ontario seems to be the most clear. From [Government of Ontario website](http://www.ontario.ca/driving-and-roads/exchange-out-province-drivers-licence):

> You can exchange an out-of-province licence for an Ontario licence, if you are re-locating from ... Republic of Ireland.

Saskatchewan is less clear. From [Government of Saskatchewan website](http://www.economy.gov.sk.ca/immigration/drivers-licence):

> If you are a new resident to Saskatchewan and have a valid driver's licence from ... Republic of Ireland ... you can apply for a Saskatchewan licence within 90 days of moving to Saskatchewan.  ***In most cases***, you will be able to get a Saskatchewan licence issued without taking a road test.

Manitoba has changed recently, as reported by the [Irish Times](http://www.irishtimes.com/news/politics/oireachtas/second-canadian-province-to-accept-irish-driving-licences-1.2197317):

> An agreement has been signed between the Road Safety Authority [of Ireland] and the province of Manitoba allowing for the exchange of licences.

**UPDATE 2015-06-23:** British Columbia has made an exchange agreement with Ireland similar to Ontario. ([link](http://moving2canada.com/living-in-canada/drivers-license-in-canada/))